# How would I go about finding the median of a row for each of another row in my Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sorry about the confusing phrasing, I have a dataframe with a variable called test_id. The dataframe looks something like this:

| test_id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1234 |
| 100 | 3132 |
| 100 | 2300 |
| 101 | 332 |
| 101 | 3242 |
| 101 | 33442 |
| 102 | 3212 |
| 102 | 111332 |
| 102 | 9842 |

I would like to find the median of the number row, but for each test id. I have tried a few ways but none have worked, and rounding has confused me.

I would like my final result to look like this:

| test_id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3132 |
| 101 | 3242 |
| 102 | 111332 |

Sorry if this is a simple question, I am relatively new to pandas and dataframes in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.groupby()` and then use `.median()`:

```py
df.groupby(["test_id"])["number"].median()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried .med() but it didn't work so I gave up.

Comment: `.med()` or `.median()`?